# Solaris 10 and 11 headers incompatible! What to do?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, solaris

We have a product we ship on Solaris amd64 (and x86, SPARC) - we have single pkg that installs on Solaris 10 and 11.

We call some functions from `/usr/include/bsm/audit.h`, specifically `getaudit_addr`, and between Solaris 10 and 11 the ABI changed dramatically, for a start reordering the struct fields and changing their lengths:

```
struct auditinfo_addr {
    au_mask_t       ai_mask;
    au_id_t         ai_auid;
    au_asid_t       ai_asid;
    au_tid_addr_t   ai_termid;
}; /* Sol 11 version */

struct auditinfo_addr {
    au_id_t         ai_auid;
    au_mask_t       ai_mask;
    au_tid_addr_t   ai_termid;
    au_asid_t       ai_asid;
}; /* Sol 10 version */
```

So, our code uses `dlopen`/`dlsym` to get a handle to `getaudit_addr`, which unsurprisingly bails out in a horrible way if you compile on Sol10 and run on Sol11 (because we're using a completely mangled structure). This is not good.

### Question

1. <s>Would we be OK if we linked with `-lbsm` rather than used `dlopen`? If so, how, because I can't find any version of the Sol10 ABI symbols inside Sol11's libbsm.so using `nm` (and both Sol10 and Sol11's version of libbsm have the following version symbols: SUNW_0.7, SUNW_0.8, SUNW_1.1, SUNW_1.2).</s> **Update:** No, linking with `-lbsm` on Solaris 10 doesn't make the code run correctly on Solaris 11. It's just a disgusting breaking ABI change they made. Grr.
2. If Solaris does have symbol versioning that works, can we do it dynamically?
3. I'm inclined to copy the structure definitions and do a run-time switch between the old and new ones rather than use the headers. Is there another fall-back solution?
4. Do the headers depend on the architecture? That is, is `audit.h` identical on SPARC, amd64, and x86? Obviously the size of typedef'd types may change, but will I need to hunt down a Solaris 11 SPARC machine to copy its header and check whether it matches the x86 one?

Comment: Very unlike Sun/Oracle to renege on Interface Stability classifications ... but also, these days, not very likely to get an explanation out of them _why_ that happened. It might be possible to inquire via the Binary Compatibility guarantee program, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/overview/guarantee-jsp-135402.html - does your test program pass on Solaris 10 when run via `appcert` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really, if the ABI is incompatible you need to treat this in the same way as if it was an incompatible processor type. That is: Build two versions. Install or build the correct version from your installer. Check at runtime you are running the correct version, and quit if you are not.

Alternatively, if this is literally the only structure which changes, you could get away with a typedef'd `auditinfo_addr_v10` vs `auditinfo_addr_v11`, and ship with either two versions of every function which uses the struct, or have a conversion function which is used on V10 to convert everything to the latest structure. I.e. supply your own `getaudit_addr_wrapper` which takes a v11 structure but will convert to the correct call on v10.

Comment: That's my option #3, I've just coded it up and it does work. I wish there were a better way of working this out though. Do you have any Solaris knowledge that would help with #4, ie will SPARC have different struct definitions to amd64 or can I use the amd64 Sol11 header for the prototypes on all arches?

Comment: The reason for the structure change is to support ipv6 addresses, which the older format didn't support. The different platforms will share the same struct definitions - unless that header file is actually in a platform/hardware specific location, it can be considered platform neutral.

Comment: @Petesh, Thanks, that's very helpful to know. Regarding IPv6 - surely the Sol10 au_tid_addr supported this? It's explicitly big enough for an IPv6 address. The only thing they've changed on Sol11 is to make the port number 64 bit, rather than 32 bit, so presumably they have something other than IP in mind there. AFAICT, the most important change is in the mask field, which has been expanded from 32 to 64 bit and re-packed in the ucred in a weird way - I can believe that running out of mask bits was urgent enough to press them to break the ABI.

Comment: Solaris has to perform this remapping itself if you're using an S10 zone on an S11 system. I can only surmise that the change was everything to do with *forward* ABI compatibility. It allows them to change the size of the last element of the ai_termid structure without disturbing the ai_asid location.

Comment: @Petesh So is there a way to get the Sol10 software to work on a Sol11 system without putting it in a zone? Is there a symbol I can grab on Sol11 that will accept the Sol10 structure layout? Having two versions of the code with runtime detection to support Sol11 is really not nice.

Comment: @NicholasWilson Stick with run-time detection. The function is private, so the structure should be considered stable within a release only. If you disassemble the function you can see that it does nothing more than invoke the `audit` system call, so you're probably going to have to change it in the future

Comment: @Petesh Private? It's in the man page officially declared as "Interface Stability: Stable"! http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getaudit_addr&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.10&arch=default&format=html Did they sell us out, or am I misinterpreting their classification? It's source-compatible, but the ABI changed in Sol11 - surely that's not normal in "Stable" interfaces?

Comment: @NicholasWilson I would be leery of quoting a non Solaris man page as a reference. They reclassified it as private, I don't actually know the reason why, but they are entitled to do this. To quote [Darren Moffat](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2152559): Those APIs have been removed.

Comment: @Petesh that explains what happened ... but it's very unlike Sun/Oracle to renege on the interface classification promises. The Solaris 10 01/13 (latest) manpage, btw, of course also states "Stable": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5167/setaudit-2.html although, to be pedantic, it doesn't _declare_ `struct auditinfo_addr` in detail.